# std::move triggered destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm adapting to an interface with parameter `const vector<pair<int32_t, A>>& as`.

To avoid multi-construct and multi-destruct, I write `CreateAs` as follow.

I was expecting it to trigger `create` `move` `del` each for once, but it turned out triggered `move` and `del` for twice.

- What's the reason?
- I made this way so that the `A` objects could destroy themselves automatically, even with `new` but without `delete`. Am I doing it right?

To reproduce it: https://repl.it/@unix1/ShrillFirsthandAdvance

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    A() { cout << "A()" << endl; }
    A(int32_t a) : a_(a) { cout << "Create A: " << a << endl; }
    A(const A& oa) { a_ = oa.a_; cout << "Copy A: " << oa.a_ << endl; }
    A(A& oa) { a_ = oa.a_; cout << "Copy A non-const: " << oa.a_ << endl;  }
    A(const A&& oa) { a_ = oa.a_; cout << "Move A: " << oa.a_ << endl; }
    A(A&& oa) { a_ = oa.a_; cout << "Move A non-const: " << oa.a_ << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "Del A: " << a_ << ", ptr: " << this << endl; }

    int32_t a_;
};

void CreateAs(vector<pair<int32_t, A>>& as) {

    as.reserve(3);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        A* a = new A(i*i);
        cout << "a ptr: " << &a << endl;
        cout << "-----before insert----" << endl;
        as.emplace_back(make_pair(i, move(*a)));
        cout << "-----after insert-----" << endl;
    }
}

void Test() {
    vector<pair<int32_t, A>> as;
    cout << "-----Create begin----" << endl;
    CreateAs(as);
    cout << "-----Create end------" << endl;
    for (const auto& item : as) {
        cout << item.first << "->" << item.second.a_ << endl;
    }
}

int main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test();
    cout << "____end test____" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `make_pair` constructs an `A` in a `pair`. `emplace_back` moves the `pair` and therefore `A` into the vector. The moved from `pair` is destroyed, also destroying the contained `A`.

Comment: Why not just `as.emplace_back(i, std::move(*a));`? That's the purpose of emplacing.

Comment: A note: your `for` loop creates a memory leak. The object created with `new A(i*i);` is never destroyed, it participates in the move, but a `move` does not destroy the object you move from.

Comment: @t.niese I thought the memory will be recycled outside `Test()`, am I right?

Comment: @DanielLangr I replaced the code as you said, it works as expected.

Comment: @RoyHuang The memory will not be recycled. You have to explicitly `delete` every pointer you create with `new`

Comment: @Mestkon Thanks for help. Did you ran the code?  It triggered `delete` after `Test()` executed.

Comment: @RoyHuang Yes, that is the destruction of `A`s in the vector you created, not the memory you `new`ed. If you put a `delete a;` at the end of your `for` loop you will see an extra set of destructors running.

Comment: Objects created with `new` have `dynamic` storage duration, these will not be "recycled". For objects with `automatic` storage duration `A  a = A(i*i)` the compiler could (in combination with a `move`)  and depending on how it is used in the code, optimize it in a way that the object you move to and the object you moved from are treated as the same object e.g. if the object you move from is not used after that point and the one you move to also has `automatic` storage duration. But any object you allocate with `new` must be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

`make_pair` constructs an `A` in a pair. `emplace_back` moves the `pair` and therefore `A` into the vector. The moved from `pair` is destroyed, also destroying the contained `A`.

Comment: Which constructor does it trigger on `make_pair`, I could not see it in  the printed message.

Comment: The move constructor. The first move into the `pair` in `make_pair`. The second move into the vector from the temporary `pair`. The destructor in the destruction of the temporary `pair`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid any move, you might do

```
void CreateAs(std::vector<std::pair<int32_t, A>>& as) {
    as.reserve(3);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        as.emplace_back(i, i*i);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad5c2b86fc1f32a6)

You currently have extra move with your extra `make_pair`.

Comment: As your demo shows, it doesn't even invoke `move` constructor at all? why?

Comment: `emplace_back` constructs in place with given arguments, something like `new (&as.back()) std::pair<int32_t, A>(i, i*i)`.